# Как расшифровать base64, которое я перехватил в приложении Andriod

Tags: base64, decode

вот код, который идет на сервер с приложения, перехваченный с помощью wireshark. как его декодировать? Здесь происходит аутентификация пользователя.

{"data":"Msz8BeoQ88G2qPtInwcz/NdSBqUFMi1SueXg/kF6C2UIDk+Ww7QX4DlgcsrOrjAPs1ny6Yf8dmLezy1vWBrXLMbqdeDwIP2syDW7kvBziYSyyd8HyqOW6moT0JrFxcXYKAgbDjx1ShtTLhqWYL9usT3LlH9Pdn2NstRyTnilHNw=","checksum":"MTZkZjE1ZjJlNDMwYmRmYw=="}

но никакие base64 не могут его декодировать. очевидно, что я не полностью это декодировал, а только то, что декодеры по идее могут прочесть. вот конкретно то, что после data никак не расшифровывается. помогите!

Comment: `data`, видимо, содержит 128 байт бинарных данных, а `checksum` - 16 байт текстовых. С помощью `echo "<base64_text>" | base64 -d` всё прекрасно декодируется

Comment: не могу пройти мимо, чтобы не посмотреть в чужой json... я попробовал - кажется, там всё таки какието бинарные данные

Comment: получается в терминале какая то ересь.. нечитаемо